# How do I add JS files inside libraries conditionally based on versions of IE7 and IE8?

Tags: 8, javascript

In Drupal 8, how would you load a JS file inside a library to only load on IE8 but not lte IE7?

I have the following added which correctly loads only on IE8 and lower.

```
js:
    js/script.js: { browsers: { IE: 'lte IE 8', '!IE': false } }
```

But, how would I only load this on IE8? and also how would I load a different js file for IE7? Would this work for example:

```
js:
    js/script.js: { browsers: { IE: 'IE 7', '!IE': false } }
```

Answer (score 5):

You have the right idea. You can do what you've done for IE7 with IE8 as well.

```
js:
  js/script7.js: { browsers: { IE: 'IE 7', '!IE': false } }
  js/script8.js: { browsers: { IE: 'IE 8', '!IE': false } }
```

Comment: Thanks @Jaypan - Yeah it works great. Although it prints out commented in the older browsers but still loads. Guess it's just an older browser issue.

Comment: That's how conditional comments work - they are printed out, but only picked up by Internet Explorer. Glad it worked for you.